# Como selecionar informações de uma tabela sem valores duplicados

Tags: sql

Digamos que tenho uma tabela chamada `ALUNOS`, com 3 colunas, `ID`, `NAME`, `SOBRENOME`
E eu queira pegar todos SOBRENOMES, mas de maneira que não duplique caso um aluno tenha o mesmo sobrenome que outro aluno.

Comment: tente usar `DISTINCT` na instrução `SELECT` ex:`SELECT DISTINCT` [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta usar `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT SOBRENOME FROM ALUNOS;
```

> Alternativas:
>   Usar um `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT SOBRENOME FROM ALUNOS GROUP BY SOBRENOME;
```

Comment: É exatamente isso, valeu!

Comment: o GROUP BY seria para contagem?

Comment: Não para contagem seria: SELECT COUNT(*).

Comment: Ah valeu! Eu estava tentando de outra forma.

Comment: E para retornar a contagem junto com a seleção seria possível?

Answer (score 1):

Basta usar `distinct`

```
SELECT DISTINCT sobrenome FROM alunos;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pra isso basta você fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (NOME) FROM TABELA;
```

Assim, virá apenas um nome se existirem vários iguais.